# Access Denied - Google Cloud MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I want to insert a local csv file into a MySQL instance on Google Cloud using Workbench but I cannot figure out how to grant FILE permissions.

In `IAM` my e-mail has `Owner` and `Cloud SQL Admin` rights, but whenever I try to grant a user `FILE` privileges, I get:

> Access denied for user''@'%' (using password:YES)

How can I set the privileges?

Comment: It looks like workbench isn't sending the db user? There should be a db username inbetween the first quotes on that error message...

Comment: Are you using Google Cloud SQL for MySQL or your own self-hosted instance?

Comment: Why do you want to grant FILE permission?

Comment: @GabeWeiss yes there is, I just left it out in the post. I also tried with the root user, then the error message would look like this: Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password:YES)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere as far as I understood, I need FILE permissions to upload a local csv file to the db using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Comment: @JohnHanley I use Google Cloud SQL for MySQL, MySQL Version 5.7

Comment: @hunter-gatherers, you need to use the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to customize the CSV format and charset, correct? It's not for importing the file, isn't it?

Comment: LOAD_FILE and LOAD DATA INFILE aren't supported for MySQL on Cloud SQL.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features#unsupported_functions